# slicing the third element of each array from of a list of arrays (python)

Tags: numpy, slice

I have a dictionary whose first element of the key 'Groups' contains a list of arrays.

```
stump['Groups'][0]

[array(['a', 65000, 0], dtype=object),
 array(['a', 95000, 1], dtype=object),
 array(['b', 78000, 1], dtype=object),
 array(['b', 19000, 1], dtype=object)]
```

I want to slice the third column of each row and do some operations on them. 
So the third columnvalues would be [0,1,1,1].

```
stump['Groups'][0][:]
#results in the whole list
[array(['a', 65000, 0], dtype=object),
 array(['a', 95000, 1], dtype=object),
 array(['b', 78000, 1], dtype=object),
 array(['b', 19000, 1], dtype=object)]
```

However, adding another indexer/slicer in front of `[:]`, just slices a portion of that list.

Anyway to do this without loops?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List comprehension should do the job:

```
[row[2] for row in stump['Groups'][0]]
```

and to work with the list as an array:

```
np.array([...])
```

The elements of this list

```
array(['a', 65000, 0], dtype=object)
```

are object dtype arrays, roughly the same as a list of the same things.  They have mixed values.

If you wrap the whole list in `np.array` (or `np.stack`) you get a 2d object dtype array

```
In [58]: arr=np.array(alist)
In [59]: arr.shape
Out[59]: (4, 3)
In [60]: arr
Out[60]: 
array([['a', 65000, 0],
       ['a', 95000, 1],
       ['b', 78000, 1],
       ['b', 19000, 1]], dtype=object)
```

That can be indexed as any other 2d array:

```
In [61]: arr[:,2]
Out[61]: array([0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=object)
```

`astype(int)` could turn that object array into a numeric one.  The full 2d one can't be converted due to the string elements.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that I can just turn the list into array, which will allow me to index just as any 2d array. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension => returns List object

```
column_list = [row[2] for row in stump['Groups'][0]]
```

map function => returns map object

```
column_map = map(lambda row: row[2], stump['Groups'][0])
```

itertools.imap function => returns iterator

```
column_iterator = itertools.imap(lambda row: row[2], stump['Groups'][0])
```

numpy array slice -> returns numpy.array.
requires stump['Groups'][0] to be of numpy.array type

```
columns_array = stump['Groups'][0][:,2]
```